# Keep receiving errors when trying to randomly choose object from a class

Tags: python, class

I am attempting to choose a random object from options within a class and I keep receiving an attribute error, I'll give the necessary pieces of the code I have as well as the specific error below:

```
import random

#creating male shirt class
class MaleShirt():
    temp = ""
    style = ""

    def __init__(self, temp, style):
        self.temp = temp
        self.style = style
        return None

    #setters and getters
    def setTemp(self, temp):
        self.temp = temp

    def getTemp(self):
        return self.temp

    def setStyle(self, style):
        self.style = style

    def getStyle(self):
        return self.style

    def explain(self):
        print('Wear a', self.getStyle(), 'shirt when it is', self.getTemp(), 'outside')

#classifying shirts
maleshirt1 = MaleShirt('hot', 'boho')
maleshirt2 = MaleShirt('cold', 'preppy')
maleshirt3 = MaleShirt('hot', 'hipster')

#randomly choosing shirt (where I get the error)
choice = random.choice(MaleShirt.maleshirt1(), MaleShirt.maleshirt2(), MaleShirt.maleshirt3())
if choice == MaleShirt.maleshirt1():
    maleshirt1.explain()
if choice == MaleShirt.maleshirt2():
    maleshirt2.explain()
if choice == MaleShirt.maleshirt3():
    maleshirt3.explain()
```

The attribute error I receive every time tells me "type object 'MaleShirt' has no attribute 'maleshirt1'" Please let me know how I can fix this!

Comment: objects that you create from a class aren't accessed using the class' name. When referring to your objects just use their variable names: `maleshirt1`, `maleshirt2`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's pretend each model of a car gets its own factory. So we have a factory for Trucks, Sedans, and Vans. The factory makes individual cars and sells them to you. When you want to drive your truck, you don't go to the Truck factory and ask where your truck is. You should know where your truck is. It is in front of your house.

It's the same here with objects and classes. Your `MaleShirt` class is the car factory. It makes `MaleShirt` objects. You "bought" three `MaleShirt` objects: `maleshirt1`, `maleshirt2`, and `maleshirt3`. When you want to use them, instead of asking the factory for them, you must know where they are and what their names are. You can then "use" them with their names: `maleshirt1.explain()`, etc.

When you ask the factory for them (`MaleShirt.maleshirt1()`) the factory tells you it doesn't know where they are

> type object 'MaleShirt' has no attribute 'maleshirt1'

because they belong to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused about how to reference an instance of an object.

```
maleshirt1 = MaleShirt('hot', 'boho')
```

`maleshirt1` is an instance

```
MaleShirt.maleshirt1()
```

Would have to be a class or static method of `MaleShirt`.

What you need the object itself i.e. `maleshirt1` (and 2 and 3).
So instead do this

```
choice = random.choice([maleshirt1, maleshirt2, maleshirt3])
if choice == maleshirt1:
    maleshirt1.explain()
elif choice == maleshirt2:
    maleshirt2.explain()
elif choice == maleshirt3:
    maleshirt3.explain()
```

You could also neaten up your `explain` method to print a string rather than a tuple.

```
def explain(self):
        print('Wear a %s shirt when it is %s outside' % (self.style, self.temp))
```

The `if` statements are actually unnecessary, you only need.

```
choice.explain()
```

As whatever is returned from `random.choice` is a `MaleShirt` and hence has an `explain` method.